# What does the word 「たしけて」mean?

Tags: words, manga

It is said by a boy who was running away from a danger situation.

Is it an alternated version of the word 「助ける」? Which dialect is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would say that it is only a lisping pronunciation of 「たすけて」 = "Help!"

I would not call it dialectal unless this character says other words or phrases that are clearly dialectal.

Answer (score 4):

in this case,
助けて【たすけて:tasukete】is right.
（means "help me."）

Comment: 「たしけて」は純粋に誤りであって、「たすけて」の書き間違い/打ち間違いである、というご意見でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

I agree with l'électeur, but it might just be a spelling mistake. I and U are next to each other on the keyboard.

Comment: 手書きもあります　→　https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGVoPkmuzAu-k7akKGcOkCs-ibEQqFVjPrq3R6pWLYcjF7vB_--A　・　http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CjjwgYUVEAAWVqM.jpg

Comment: おそらく、かわいい印象を与えるために、作者がわざと「たしけて」を書いたと思います。ただし、個人的な経験をもとに、単なるスペルミスの可能性があることを指摘したかっただけ。